# Change class of $(this)

Tags: jquery, css

I have a `<span>` button, which calls some jQuery, I need a way to then disable it (and if possible, it's corresponding up/down button) from being repeatedly clicked. I have made event handlers for the buttons as such:

```
$('.RateDown').click(function() {

    //down counter
    var downValue = parseInt($(this).text());
    downValue--;
    $(this).text(downValue);

    //total counter
    var totalValueElement = $(this).prevAll('.RateTotal').first();
    var totalValue = parseInt(totalValueElement.text());
    totalValue--;
    totalValueElement.text(totalValue);
});
```

(And a similar one for RateUp)

And the relevant HTML as follows

```
<div class='RateBar'>
    <span class='RateTotal'>0</span><br />
    <span class='RateUp'> +0</span>
    <span class='RateDown'> -0</span>
</div>
```

This works for the moment, but anyone can repeatedly spam the button, so I was thinking that if I change it's class to a "Rated" one, that it would not be click-able. I have tried using the `.attr()` feature, but this does not succeed. Is it possible to disable it in this way, or some other way? I have played around with a disabled boolean, changing it on click, but with multiple buttons on a page, this is impractical.

(The buttons are currently [here](http://nic-dart.tk/))

Comment: `$(this).addClass('rated')` or `$(this).prevAll('.RateTotal').addClass('rated')`

Comment: Are you looking for `.addClass()`/`.removeClass()`/`.toggleClass()`?

Comment: every time you use `parseInt` without a radix, Doug Crockford drowns an adorable teacup piglet. `parseInt('07') == 7, parseInt('09') = 9, parseInt('010') = 8`. Instead: `parseInt($(this).text(), 10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery .one on the click event - it binds only once. - http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class and remove the click handler:

```
$(this).addClass("disabled").off("click");
```

And similarly for the other button:

```
$(this).siblings(".RateUp").addClass("disabled").off("click");
```

**NOTE:** `off` was added in 1.7, for previous versions, use `unbind`.

Answer (score 0):

You got some options:

```
$(this).attr('class','rated');
```

This would change your class to rated and thereby the span is not clickable.

Another, maybe better solution would be:

```
$(this).unbind('click');
```

Now the span is not clickable anymore but keeps it classes and whatever style is tied to it.